# EditText keeps writing in single line Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I know this question has been asked before and I tried several answers but none of them worked. I have an EditText where the user gives caption of a picture. The editText keeps writing the text in a single line. It doesn't go to the next line. I want the text to go to next line automatically when it reaches the screen's border/end. Here's my code. Please let me know if I have made any mistakes in my code.

```
<EditText
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine|textPersonName"
                android:hint="Write some thing about the photo"
                android:maxLength="160"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/privacyHolder"
                android:lines="3"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:ems="20"
                android:paddingEnd="4dp"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
                android:id="@+id/description"
                />
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Resource, design your edit text as follow:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text|textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
    android:gravity="left"
     />
```

In the activity you can use TextWatcher to listen when text exceeds few character and automatically move down.

Here is the snippet :

```
private boolean isReach = false;

// put this in onCreate method
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // if edittext has 20 character reached add a new line, you can use either 20 or more here
        if(yourtextEd.getText().length() == 20 && !isReach) {
            yourtextEd.append("\n");
            isReach = true;
        }
        // if edittext has less than 20 characters and isReach has set , change
        if(yourtextEd.getText().length() < 20 && isReach) isReach = false;
    }
});
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: sorry for late response. I tried the solution but unfortunately this doesn't work :(